Puppet on Forti os, Is it possible?
I basicaly wanted to know if it is possible to download and configure puppet-client on a fortigate to be able to push configuration manifests from the puppet-server ? I already know that some tools are already doing it such as forti manager and ansible but i was wondering if puppet would work.
Thanks in advance !

No, that's not possible - you cannot install any software on a FortiGate other than the intended firmware.
Puppet - or any other management software - needs to use the integrated management options, including SNMP, the REST API, or the SSH console.

ok, tank you Zac !
